# iPad: How to write on sticky notes with Pencil in Freeform

Tags: ios, ipados, apple-pencil

Im currently trying out freeform and was surprised to find out that I can not write anything with my Pencil on sticky notes. I can add text to sticky notes the usual ways, but anything writen with Apple Pencil is not attached to the sticky note. I.e. if I move the sticky note my writen text doenst move along with it.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution works for both iPad and iPhone.

After creating a sticky note you can draw/write on it with your pencil, but in order to keep the drawing attached to the note you have to group it:

1. De-select the drawing tool, if selected
2. Tap on the whiteboard: it will show "Select objects", tap on it
3. Now you can select both the sticky note and your drawing on it by sliding over them
4. Tap on "done"/"end"
5. A menu pops up, close the selection you made: tap on the left-most option (grouping option)
6. Tap on group

Now your drawing it attached to you sticky note on every synced devices.

Alternatively after (1.) you can tap, hold for 2 seconds, and slide over the objects you want to select. Then continue from (5.)

Comment: Works! Not really convenient or "smart" from Apples side, but works.